# Problem adding variable in JQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I'm developing a table and I need to add text in some cells of this table. The **column of the cell is setted with a variable in the selector** to know where to add the text.

This is the code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm" id="agenda">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th><p style="display: none;">0</p></th>
   <th>Mon</th>
   <th>Tue</th>
   <th>Wed</th>
   <th>Thu</th>
   <th>Fri</th>
   <th>Sat</th>
   <th>Sun</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="agenda-body">
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
 //more code
 </tbody>
</table>
```

```
var day = 1;
var number_columns = 3;
for (let i = number_columns + 1 ; i < 10; i++){
 $('#agenda-body > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child("' + day + '")').html(day);
 day = day + 1;
 console.log(day);
}
```

I'm getting the next error:

[image]

Any suggestion?
Thanks for reading!

Comment: Get rid of those double-quote (`"`) characters.

Comment: This `$('#agenda-body > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(' + day + ')').html(day);`

Comment: Thanks fot the answers, it worked! @Pointy

Comment: Also, consider using modern template strings instead, so you're not using string breaking and +

Answer (score 1):

Remove the double quotes in `nth-child("...")`. Check the following code. The fix is `td:nth-child(' + day + ')`

```js
var day = 1;
var number_columns = 3;
for (let i = number_columns + 1; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log('#agenda-body > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(' + day + ')');
  $('#agenda-body > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(' + day + ')').html(day);
  day = day + 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm" id="agenda">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <p style="display: none;">0</p>
      </th>
      <th>Mon</th>
      <th>Tue</th>
      <th>Wed</th>
      <th>Thu</th>
      <th>Fri</th>
      <th>Sat</th>
      <th>Sun</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="agenda-body">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    //more code
  </tbody>
</table>
```